# Firebird Partial selection after and including character in Table

Tags: firebird

Not sure if what I want to do is possible
But here it goes

A sql select command like...

```
select origtxno from posinvtrans
```

will return a value like
    1-5454 or 23-54545 etc.

What I am after is removing everything before and including "-" in a select
example 1-5454 will be 5454 and 23-54545 will be 54545

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substring(origtxno from position('-', origtxno) + 1)
from posinvtrans
```

Comment: @user2516423 - That was a typo. Updated the answer.